# How to validate a single parameter in DropWizard

Tags: java, validation, jersey, dropwizard

I want to validate some input parameters in DropWizard as documented here: https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#validation

This example validates an object's properties, which works fine, but my service doesn't receive an object, but the parameters directly. This is a simplification of my code:

```
@GET
@Path("/MyResource/{myresourceId}")
public MyResource detail(@PathParam("myresourceId") @Valid @Size(min = 2, max = 5) String myresourceId) {
```

The @Valid and @Size annotations seem to be ignored in this case.
Anyone knows if this is possible and if so how to do it right? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/wb6iwrpSrSE

Comment: ok, it seems then it's not possible with the current version of dropwizard.. @condit if you want to put that in an answer I'll close this question, thanks

Comment: do you think this is supported now in dropwizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with those annotations as method parameters. Have a look at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/wb6iwrpSrSE).

You might be able to write some AOP code to support this (depending on how you're initializing your resources).